# How to build stacked rows of text in blocks: text widget or canvas?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to stack text vertically in "blocks" and organize those blocks from right to left to display an interlinear view of Bible verses along with the original Hebrew. Generally, that is one block per original word, as displayed below for two such blocks.

```
          H1254               H7225
          bā·rā           bə·rê·šîṯ
            בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית              בָּרָ֣א  
        created    In the beginning
 V‑Qal‑Perf‑3ms       Prep‑b | N‑fs
```

I'm confused on how to approach this or whether it should be done in a text widget or canvas? Each row of text will have different fonts and tags, and the tags have different bindings.

Is the correct approach to use a canvas and plot each word separately since the fonts are different? I assume the canvas width can be fixed and then determine the width of the largest text row in each block to determine how many blocks can fit per row.

Perhaps I'm being stupid here and it's not that hard.  The only GUI experience I have is with the box model and flex box makes this quite easy; so, I figure Tk can do that also and I'm just not seeing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with either. Obviously, with the canvas you can just place the text wherever you want (using the bounding boxes of the text items to help you work out the placement) but it is somewhat do-it-yourself.

If you're doing it with a text widget, you need to set up suitable tabs and tags. In particular, set up tabs so that text aligns how you want it to. Tab settings default to the classic “every 8 characters” style, but you should instead use something like:

```
.t configure -tabs {5c right}
```

so you can insert text like this (NB: I don't read Hebrew at all so I *really* can't tell you if that line is coming out right):

```
set dataSource {
          H1254               H7225
          bā·rā           bə·rê·šîṯ
            בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית              בָּרָ֣א  
        created    {In the beginning}
 V‑Qal‑Perf‑3ms       {Prep‑b | N‑fs}
}
# You've got a better data source than a literal list, but it's good for testing

set aWidth 0
set bWidth 0
set font [.t cget -font]
foreach {a b} $dataSource {
    set aWidth [expr {max($aWidth, [font measure $font $a])}]
    set bWidth [expr {max($bWidth, [font measure $font $b])}]
    .t insert end \t$a\t$b\n
}
.t configure -tabs [list [expr {$aWidth + 10}] right [expr {$aWidth + $bWidth + 20}] right]
```

Note that I've integrated measuring the text (with `font measure`) so as to work out the tab positions from the data. (The 10 and 20 are just a little extra space so that you can see what's going on.)

Use tags to apply styles to ranges of text, such as different fonts, or to make the text able to respond to clicks.

```
set tagName "Title"
.t tag configure $tagName -font {Arial 18 bold} -foreground red
.t tag bind $tagName <1> {puts "Clicked on title"}
.t tag add $tagName 1.0 1.end
# You can also apply tags when inserting
# .t insert end "Example" $tagName
```

You can have a lot of tags present on a range of characters if you want; there's a priority system with the property that actually applies being the one from the highest-priority tag that specifies it (or from the overall widget's configuration properties if nothing else chips in).

Comment: If you're changing fonts, you'll probably need to bear that in mind when measuring the text…

Comment: Thank you for the working example and pointers; they are very helpful.